# How to obtain the value of a clicked Hashtag in a post with an arbitrary number of Hashtags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an observable array viz: `listData = ko.observableArray([])`. I am able to handle a click on the observable and obtain the item that was clicked.

Each of the items has an `itemId` and `post`. The `post` part can have arbitrary number of Hashtags. For instance, item 1 post may be like this:

> "Hey, did you check out my new #Article on #SocialMedia?"

Now we have a new requirement: when I click on a hashtag (which will be wrapped in `<a href="#">#SocialMedia</a>`) I want to obtain the value of that href, i.e. "#SocialMedia".

Is this possible in Knockout? Kindly provide a little code sample to point me on the right direction.

Comment: Heya, welcome to Stack Overflow! It'd help if you edit your question and add the code you have so far, set a situation with a repro, and tell us what you've tried so far. Currently your question reads as if it's just a requirement that needs to be done.

Comment: @Jeroen,  he is obviously new to jQuery (do not be offended, we were all newbies :) ), piece of code is not required in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would go for something like

```
$("a:contains('#')").click(function() {
     var HashTagValue = $(this).text();
});
```

this is untested but i dont think it wont work.

Comment: Magnificent! So here is what I did, I added this function:
 

`hashtagClick: function () {
            $("a:contains('#')").click(function () {
                var HashTagValue = $(this).text();
                alert(HashTagValue)
            });
        }`

Now when I click a hashtag the first time, nothing happens. The second time, the alert is displayed with the value of the hashtag (AWESOME!). The third time, the alert is displayed twice, and so it continues incrementally irrespective of whichever hashtag I click.

Thanks @ori-refael! Any thoughts about the repeat alerts?

Comment: easy, you are calling the .click function too many times, you shuold only trigger it once, if you define it more than 1 time, the click function will be called multiple times, can you provide the piece of code of where you call the function? if it works, i would appreciate if you mark the question as answer and upvote this :)

Comment: I am calling it from a PhoneJs mobile application. I accept your answer because it works. Maybe the issue has to do with Devexpress Devextreme DXList binding I am using. I will head on over to Devexpress and find out more. Once again, thanks a million!

Comment: it seems you attached the .click event to a method, everytime you call this method you add another click event listener which causes for multiple call. pay attention that the first time isn't happening probably due to the fact that the div isn't exist when the event bounding is called. therefor, the event listener isn't being attached to anything - because its not created yet.

Comment: thank you. I am investigating it as you suggested. While new to Javascript (I am core C# developer and know little about Javascript), but your explanation is perfectly logical. I asked the question on Devexpress site with your code above as reference. They'll answer on Monday and I will update this thread accordingly. Once again, thanks!

Comment: sure thing, im a C# developer as well, C# and Javascript has completely different handling, good luck !

Comment: Hi! The guys over at Devexpress provided this code which works perfect. Here:

`hashtagClick: function (e) {
            var target = e.jQueryEvent.target;
            var a_array = e.element.find("a:contains('#')");
            var res_array = $.grep(a_array, function (item) {
                return item == target;
            });
            if (res_array.length)
                alert($(res_array[0]).text());
}`

In case anyone will need this in the future!

Comment: thats exactly prevents the bug i told you are causing :). now i know what you did that caused the multiple calling